# Does $v\in L^p$ imply the derivative or integral of $v$ also in $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

And furthermore, will the composition $(voF)$ be also in $L^p$ if $F$ is bijective and $v\in L^p$.

Comment: // EDIT: I found a counter-example for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding the title:**
The answer is no. Consider $(X,\mathcal A, \mu) = ((0,1), \mathcal B \cap (0, 1), \lambda)$ and take $v(x) = \ln(x)$ then the derivative is in no $L^p$, but $v\in L^p$

---

**Regarding the body:**
The answer is no again, with the example of $(X,\mathcal A, \mu) = ((1,\infty), \mathcal B \cap (1, \infty), \lambda)$, $v(x) = \frac1{x^2}$ and $F(x) = \sqrt x$ such that
$$v\circ F(x) = \frac1{|x|} \notin L^p$$